# Connection strings LocalDB in ASP.NET WebForms Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, connection-string, localdb

I use ASP.NET sample application using by Microsoft: WingtipToys.

It uses **LocalDB**.

Which is the difference about connection strings?

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" 
     connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\V11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WingtipToys;Integrated Security=True" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" 
     connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WingtipToys-20131223105750.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WingtipToys-20131223105750;Integrated Security=True" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I get error connection using **Data Source=(LocalDB)\V11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WingtipToys;Integrated Security=True**

**sqlocaldb.exe** command:

```
C:\Users\Espinete>sqllocaldb.exe v
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (11.0.3156.0)
Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (12.0.2000.8)
Microsoft SQL Server 2016 Release Candidate 0 (RC0) (13.0.1100.286)

C:\Users\Espinete>sqllocaldb.exe i
MSSQLLocalDB
Projects
ProjectsV13
v11.0
```

Answer (score 1):

First, LocalDB connection strings usually has database file naming convention using unique number suffix with this format:

```
aspnet-[project name]-yyyyMMddHHmmss.mdf
```

The unique number suffix represents database creation date & time stamp at nearly same time as project creation time.

By default, when creating a LocalDB database file which not defined in any SQL Server instance, the connection string in web.config uses `AttachDBFileName` setting. The difference between `AttachDBFileName` & `Initial Catalog` setting as described in [Common Connection String Settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653752(v=vs.110).aspx#initialcatalog) is there:

**AttachDbFileName**

> This setting specifies the path and name of the database file for SQL
>   Server Express or LocalDB databases that are not defined in the local
>   SQL Server Express instance. This setting is typically used for database files that you keep in the App_Data folder.

**Initial Catalog**

> This setting specifies the name of the database in the SQL Server
>   instance catalog. In LocalDB connection strings, the Visual Studio web project templates add a unique number as a suffix to both the file name and the Initial Catalog setting. The reason for this is to avoid database name collisions in the SQL Server Express LocalDB instance.

From descriptions above, the first connection string certainly doesn't work because LocalDB doesn't know which database file should be attached into its instance. To use `Initial Catalog` without `AttachDBFileName` setting you need to attach created LocalDB database in an SQL Server instance (either using SSMS or `sqlcmd` command line utility to create DB catalog).

Difference summary between first and second connection string:

1. `Initial Catalog` without `AttachDBFileName` => trying to connect using already attached database name defined in SQL Server instance catalog.
2. `Initial Catalog` with `AttachDBFileName` => trying to attach manually & connect using database MDF file inside `App_Data` directory with `Initial Catalog` set to attached database file name in `LocalDB` instance.

NB: `sqllocaldb.exe v` command lists all installed LocalDB versions in your machine, where `sqllocaldb.exe i` lists all shared existing LocalDB instances (more info in [SqlLocalDB.exe docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/express-localdb-instance-apis/command-line-management-tool-sqllocaldb-exe)).

Additional reference:

[SqlConnection.ConnectionString Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring(v=vs.110).aspx) (MSDN)